# Export 2-D object array (Object[][] array) into a .csv file in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on a java project and using Eclipse with JDK 1.7. I have 2-D array of object type as `Object[][] array`. I wish to store the contents (export) of array to a csv file (each value in a separate column for each row) on the disk. Here is the code I'm trying:

```
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("newFile.csv");
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);  
            for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<array[0].length;j++)
                {
                   oos.writeObject(array); 
                   oos.writeObject(",");
                   }
            }
            oos.close();
```

The output stored in file `newFile.csv` is as follows:

```
¬íur[[Ljava.lang.Object;¿ûSäkÛÊxpur[Ljava.lang.Object;ÎXŸs)lxpt1t1tClosedt100.00000000t   
0.00000000uq~t2t1tClosedt200.00000000t100.00000000uq~t3t1tClosedt100.00000000t50.00000000t   q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~q~
```

which is some garbage value. I need help to figure out what is wrong in this program (how to convert object into a string before storing, this is what I'm guessing the error is), and how to resolve the issue.

I found a help on http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/io/objectinputstream_readobject.htm but it deals with `byte[]` and `String`, not with 2-D object array. Similarly, http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-write-to-file-in-java-fileoutputstream-example/ deals with `byte[]` only. I have also found a solution at [Java - How to write ArrayList Objects into txt file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065797/java-how-to-write-arraylist-objects-into-txt-file), where `ArrayList<String> MenuArray = new ArrayList<String>();` is used instead of 2-D object array, and also the solution is not complete. I also find a help at [Using FileUtils in eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13166350/using-fileutils-in-eclipse)
I'm getting the similar error.
The solution says use:

```
FileUtils.writeLines(new File("input.txt"), array);
```

However, I receive an error that `method writeLine(File, Collection<>) is not applicable for  WriteLine(File, Object[][])`.
Further a solution in ADO.NET exists for reading csv file and store data in 2-D array at [Reading a csv file and storing the data in a 2-D object array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31439718/reading-a-csv-file-and-storing-the-data-in-a-2-d-object-array), but I need the other way and also solution in not for Java.

Both the methods I used are not working. Please note my 2-D array is of `Object` type not `String`. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("newFile.csv");
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);  
        for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<array[i].length;j++)
            {
               oos.writeObject(array[i][j]); 
               if ( j < array[i].length -1 )
               {
                   oos.writeObject(",");
               } 
               else 
               {
                   oos.wrinteObject("\n");
               }
             }
        }
        oos.close();
```